# run android emulator with vanilla 3.12.6

Tags: android, kernel, emulation

I am trying to build vanilla kernel for goldfish emulator. as I know, this release (3.12.6) includes support for the goldfish platform.
I enable all goldfish and android driver, but when I trying to load the emulator I got a black screen and the adb keeps telling me that the emulator is offline...
Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: the emulator gets stuck on this point and nothing happens...     emulator: ping program: /home/Android/kitkat/out/host/linux-x86/bin/ddms